# jQuery-UI Accordion with link in the header

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using Dotclear blog software, which provide a widget for the blog categories with a resulting code looking like this:

```
<div class="widget categories ">
    <h3>Catégories</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="BlogURL/category/Cat1">Cat1</a></li>
        <li><a href="BlogURL/category/Cat2">Cat2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="BlogURL/category/Cat2/Subcat1">Subcat1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="BlogURL/category/Cat3">Cat3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="BlogURL/category/Cat3/Subcat2">Subcat2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="BlogURL/category/Cat4">Cat4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve here is using the `<a>` tag (for Cat2 or Cat3) as header (or a dynamically added `<h4>` around it) and fold the subcategory list. If I call the accordion like this :

```
    $(".categories").accordion({
        header: "li:has(ul) > a",
    });
```

the accordion does work, but when I click on the link it just folds/unfolds the item and doesn’t let me go to the link target (the category page, that is).

I tried wrapping the `<a>` in an `<h4>` tag and use that tag as header, but it doesn’t seem to make a difference. Is there a way to do what I seek or should I abandon the idea of collapsing subcategories *and* have functioning links within the header ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear what is 'not working' and what you expect to happen with it 'is working'. Please clarify the expected result and what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to be more specific. Please tell me if it’s clearer this way. I am French, so my english may be imprecise…

Comment: Are you trying to have links in the section or the header? ... The header, to me, is the `<h3>` tag with categories. If it's in the section, which is what the `<ul>` block appears to be, try putting the entire `<ul>` block inside a `<div>` tag to see if that may be what is trying to be achieved, and temporarily comment-out the `header:` portion to test.  Accordions are typically pairs of `<h3><div>` tags (though it is possible to change this combination to some extent)

Comment: @PaulT. Hello and thanks for the answer ! I have no interest in using the `<h3>` as the accordion header (even though I get that’s the initial purpose). What I am trying to achieve is folding/unfolding the « sublists » (`<ul>` inside `<li>`) when there are subcategories. I manage to make that work, with the code above, but then my links followed by folded content don’t go anywhere (just fold/unfold the following `<ul>`)

Comment: [Here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/73uph4nd/) of your code. If you click `Cat3`, then click `Subcat2`, the link works. Please explain what's not right.

Comment: yes @isherwood, the link to Subcat2 works, but not the one to Cat3. My problem is there : having a functioning link inside the accordion header ! Thanks for your POC

Comment: I don't understand. How can you use the same element to both navigate and control an accordion? Also, I can toggle those headings back and forth. I'm not sure what's not working for you.

Comment: the category menu is used for navigation, and the links in it are useful. I have a background arrow image that « signal » the unfolding possibility. I hoped I could have fold-unfold by clicking on the *line* where the link is and still access the link. I guess I’m asking too much of the accordion, and I will probably come back to a more classic menu. Or I will duplicate the text before the link and use that as the header… Thx for your input

Answer (score 0):

Well, after reading your comments, I realized I was using the wrong tool to achieve my objective. I have replaced jquery-ui’s accordion with a [treemenu jQuery plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Lightweight-Folding-Menu-Plugin-For-jQuery-treemenu-js.html) which is actually made for my use. Sorry to have wasted your time and thanks for your kind answers.